# After last item won't execute in loop salesforce flow

Tags: visual-workflow, automation

Flow won't move forward the 'After last item'
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `for each item` branch, without it, it will remain stuck, probably.

And in the second loop, `contact loop` you need to connect the last item in the `for each item` branch back to the loop to complete the cycle.